# Is this USB Hub 3.0+2.0 hybrid safe to use?

Tags: safety, usb-hub, bad-wiring

So I just bought a USB 3.0+2.0 hub hybrid. When I check the PCB, the pin out is new to me (see photo).

From host, two of the USB 2.0 data lines (red lines) went straight to the hub IC, then from the IC to the USB 3.0 port (green lines).

The USB 3.0 it superspeed datalines (yellow lines) is straight from host to the port.

The rest of hub is connected to 3 x USB 2.0 ports.

Is the USB 3.0 & USB 2.0 safe to use simultaneously?
Anyone else tested it out? I want to know before test it out myself.
fyi vbus and ground are shared on the IC and ports.

[Similar question without a product](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572539/usb-3-0-host-with-two-devices-on-one-line-a-2-0-hub-and-3-0-port).

[image: FRONT PCB]
[image: Bck PCB]
[image: wiring]
[image: IC]

EDIT:
I tested it and it works, but unsure if it is safe.

I also got another one marked as usb3.0 hub but from the pcb traces, it is similar as the ones above. this Pcb is easier to see the traces.

[image: usb hub 3 2 hybrid]